# Not able to execute ALTER SEQUENCE command through spring boot code

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

I am writing a code in spring boot 1.5.22 with java 8 and oracle 11g. Here, In my repository class, I have tried to call one native query as-

```
@Query(value = "ALTER SEQUENCE <SEQ_NAME> RESTART START WITH 0", nativeQuery = true)
void resetSequence();
```

when I try to call this method in my service Impl class, I get the following error:-

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException:-1
```

However, I can execute select sequence commands using java code as-

```
    @Query(value = "select <Seq_name>.nextVal from dual", nativeQuery = true)
    int getNextCount();
```

I don't know how exactly I can command to reset my sequence using java code/job here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `@Modifying` annotation

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ALTER SEQUENCE`is *not a query*, so it is not expected to work in the way you call it.

What *will* work is to fall back to plain JDBC and call something like this

```
con.createStatement().execute "ALTER SEQUENCE  SEQ RESTART START WITH 0"
```

Two additionally remarks

- the `ALTER SEQUENCE`is not a typical use case for *spring-data* so it should be used only in some supporting code for JUnit etc.
- You'll have to create the sequence with  `MINVALUE 0` to be able to reset it (default is 1). Otherwise you get exception `ORA-04006: START WITH cannot be less than MINVALUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Entity manager to modify a sequence and execute SQL queries that the spring boot shortcuts do not allow

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;      
@PersistenceContext
      EntityManager entityManager;
        public void resetSequence(String data) {
             entityManager
                    
                     .createNativeQuery("SELECT setval('sequence_value', "+data+", FALSE);")
                    .getSingleResult()
                    ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use entity manager to reset your sequence

---

**ORACLE**

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("DROP SEQUENCE " + seqName).executeUpdate();
entityManager.createNativeQuery("CREATE SEQUENCE " + seqName + " START WITH " + size).executeUpdate();
```

**POSTGRESQL**

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT setval(?, ?, true)")
                .setParameter(1, seqName)
                .setParameter(2, size)
                .getResultList();
```